# Varias condiciones fórmula SI Excel

Tags: excel

Tengo el siguiente problema: necesito evaluar dos condiciones en un mismo `SI`. El problema es que la condición tiene que ser `O` en vez de `Y`.

En este ejemplo sencillo evalúo que A sea menor que 0,1 y si se cumple la condición mostrará `VERDADERO` y si no pondrá `FALSO`:

```
=SI(A<0,1;VERDADERO;FALSO)
```

Pero, ¿cómo puedo poner para que A esté comprendido entre dos valores posibles? Es decir, que A sea por ejemplo > 0,1 y < 0,15?

**He probado lo siguiente**:

```
=SI(A>0,1(O(A<0,15));VERDADERO;FALSO)
```

Pero me devuelve falso cuando A por ejemplo vale 0,11.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Aunque esta pregunta ya tiene votos positivos y dos respuestas, la pregunta no es clara ya que se menciona que "El problema es que la condición tiene que ser `O` en vez de `Y` pero el ejemplo dado es sobre usar `Y`".

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con tu comentario, creo que lo que he preguntado es más que claro, necesito que se den las dos condiciones, sin más.

Comment: Entonces está sobrando "El problema es que la condición tiene que ser `O` en vez de `Y`."

Comment: @Rubén bajo tu criterio, no para el mio. Además creo que ha quedado bastante claro que la pregunta se ha entendido a la perfección porque la han respondido sobre la marcha, si hubiera albergado la más mínima duda estoy seguro que ellos mismos en vez de responder lo habrían indicado antes de darle a enviar "respuesta". Y por supuesto respeto tu decisión y opinión, pero como he dicho antes no la comparto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa la funcion `Y (condition1 ; condition2 ; ...)`

```
=SI(Y( A>0,1; A<0,15 );VERDADERO;FALSO)
```

Comment: Te he corregido la fórmula, que tenía errores

Comment: Te me has adelantado por segundos... y poner dos veces la misma respuesta no tiene sentido

Comment: @eferion gracias ^^ miré copie la documentacion y no me di cuenta. HAHAH ninja'd!

Comment: Gracias @lois6b, te valido la respuesta porque fue la primera que vi y la que puse en práctica y ha funcionado correctamente, como le he dicho a Eferion, interpreté que con el O se daban las dos posibilidades. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: @David me alegra ser de ayuda! Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

En Excel no existen, a diferencia de lo que sucede en muchos lenguajes de programación, el concepto de operador. **todo** son fórmulas.

Básicamente hay dos fórmulas para agrupar expresiones:

- `Y(condicion1;expresion2;...)`
- `O(condicion1;expresion2;...)`

Cualquiera de estas fórmulas devuelve un resultado booleano (cierto/falso) y las dos primeras admiten un número arbitrario de argumentos.

En tu caso estás diciendo:

> ¿cómo puedo poner para que A esté comprendido entre dos valores posibles? Es decir, que A sea por ejemplo > 0,1 **y** < 0,15?

Ahí estás admitiendo que las expresiones se han de agrupar con `Y` en vez de con `O`. Si las agrupas con `O` el resultado va a ser cierto **siempre** y no es lo que deseas. En efecto puedes verificar fácilmente que cualquier número va a ser o mayor que 0.1 o menor que 0.15 o ambas.

En resumen, la ecuación final quedaría así:

```
=SI(Y(A>0,1;A<0,15);VERDADERO;FALSO)
```

La explicación de la fórmula es:

- `Y(A>0,1;A<0,15)` evalúa que A se encuentre en el rango (0.1 - 0.15).
- `SI(COND;VERDADERO;FALSO)` si se cumple la condición anterior se evaluará `VERDADERO`; en caso contrario se evaluará `FALSO`

Comment: taca! venga ahi a dejarme en ridiculo xDD (kidding, está muy elaborada ^^)

Comment: normal, escribiendo 2 lineas ... xD

Comment: Gracias @eferion, no puedo validar las dos respuestas, más quisiera. Pero muchas gracias por la explicación. Ya funciona a la perfección. Había interpretado que con el O se tendría que dar las dos condiciones y era con Y.

Answer (score 2):

## Fórmula

Asumiendo que el valor a comparar se encuentra en A1,  para obtener como resultado `VERDADERO` o `FALSO`, si el valor en A1 se encuentre entre 0,1 y 0,15 basta con usar [Y()](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Y-funci%C3%B3n-Y-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9?ui=es-ES&rs=es-ES&ad=ES), ejemplo:

```
=Y(A1>0,1; A1<0,15)
```

## Explicación

> Pero, ¿cómo puedo poner para que A esté comprendido entre dos valores posibles? Es decir, que A sea por ejemplo > 0,1 y < 0,15?
>   He probado lo siguiente:
>
> =SI(A>0,1(O(A<0,15));VERDADERO;FALSO)

En la fórmula anterior hay un error claro y otros tres muy probables ya que no se indica que se hayan designado *A*, *VERDADERO* y *FALSO* como [nombres](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Definir-y-usar-nombres-en-f%C3%B3rmulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) de un rango o fórmula, ni la versión de Excel. Vamos por partes.

- Los cálculos básicos se realizan a través de fórmulas, las cuales inicia con `=`.
- Las fórmulas admiten números, cadenas de texto, funciones o referencias a celdas o rangos, "errores" (como #DIV/0), nombres definidos por el usuario.
- Las cadenas de texto deben indicarse entre comillas, ejemplo `"rojo"`. Algunas cadenas como *VERDADERO* y *FALSO* en versiones modernas de Excel con interpretados como los valores booleanos, lo cual no ocurría en versiones antiguas.
- Los operadores de fórmulas de Excel son `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`, `^`, `&`.
  Nota: La lista anterior no es exhaustiva, por ejemplo, se omiten intencionalmente `%`, `E` (estos corresponden a "notaciones numéricas") entre otros.
- Los valores booleanos se obtienen mediante una comparación usando los operadores `>`, `<`, `=`, `>=`, `<=`, mediante las funciones `VERDADERO()`, `FALSO()` o mediante las funciones lógicas `Y()`, `O()`, `NO()`.

Por ejemplo, asumiendo que en A1 está el valor a comparar, una fórmula de una única comparación sería

```
=A1>0,1
```

Lo anterior daría como resultado los valores `VERDADERO` o `FALSO`

Para evaluar si el valor en A1 cumple con dos condiciones usando la función lógicas [Y()](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Y-funci%C3%B3n-Y-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9?ui=es-ES&rs=es-ES&ad=ES)

```
=Y(A1>0,1;A1<0,15)
```

Lo anterior daría como resultado los valores `VERDADERO` o `FALSO`. Nótese que cada comparación se include como argumento de la función.

Cómo se observa, para obtener el resultado `VERDADERO` o `FALSO` no hace falta usar SI(), la cual tiene sentido cuando se desea que valores diferentes a estos sean el resultado de evaluar condiciones, por ejemplo, si en lugar de `VERDADERO` y `FALSO`, digamos que se desea como resultado "VERDE" o "ROJO" respectivamente, se puede usar

```
=SI(Y(A1>0,1; A1<0,15);"VERDE";"ROJO")
```

Nota: Existen otras formas para valorar si un valor o matriz cumple con ciertas condiciones, pero abordar todas ellas haría demasiado extensa esta publicación.

## Referencias

- [Fórmulas y Funciones](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/F%C3%B3rmulas-y-funciones-294d9486-b332-48ed-b489-abe7d0f9eda9?ui=es-ES&rs=es-ES)

Comment: Notas para ediciones futuras: Agregar `XO`